# What is the ideal temperature for water added to chickpea flour for falafel?

Tags: temperature, batter, middle-eastern-cuisine, chickpeas

Recipes for falafel using bean flour usually recommend warm, but not hot water to mix with the dry ingredients. What is the ideal temperature range for the water?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but "warm" for other purposes generally means ~100F or ~38C.

Answer (score 3):

I have always used room temperature water, & have never had any problem. Generally I take the water from the Brtia filter sitting on my countertop.